# How to find textbox value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on one project where I need to create an order form

I got a very good example from http://css-tricks.com/examples/DynamicOrderForm/.

But the problem is that the pricing here is fixed, but I need a textbox for pricing so I can change pricing also.

I tried to make it work, but failed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Show what you tried, people are happy to help you figure out where you went wrong.

Comment: i tried to make changes in JS file, but i can't put text box in place of price and get result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go down and search for

```
<td class="price-per-pallet">$<span>165</span></td>
```

and edit the prices within the "span" tag with your price. If you want a textbox

```
<input name="price" type="text" />
```

then in order.js check where the calculations are being taken place and there you can read the value of this textbox instead of reading static value of span tag. Find following line in order.js

```
// Find the pricing
        var multiplier = $el
            .parent().parent()
            .find("td.price-per-pallet span")
            .text();
```

instead of

```
.find("td.price-per-pallet span").text();
```

you can use

```
.find('td.price-per-pallet span input[name="price"]').val();
```

Hope this helps